# Line Chart (Currency)

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I'm trying to develop a line chart using a third-party API and I'm using both react-chartjs-2 and chart.js

The problem is, the line doesn't appear in the chart and I assume the reason is: the date. This is my first time to develop a web application using Chart.js. Also, I read the documentations and couldn't find a solution.

dateDate which is an array that contains all dates. The Array has dates inside of it, not objects.

I console.log'd the date in using the map loop and it worked, but it doesn't appear in the chart. I don't know the reason behind it.

Here is the console.log:

2023-01-10 App.jsx:66 2023-01-11 App.jsx:66 2023-01-12 App.jsx:66 2023-01-13 App.jsx:66 2023-01-14 App.jsx:66 2023-01-15 App.jsx:66 2023-01-16 App.jsx:66 2023-01-17 App.jsx:66 2023-01-18 App.jsx:66 2023-01-19 App.jsx:66 2023-01-20 App.jsx:66 2023-01-21 App.jsx:66 2023-01-22 App.jsx:66 2023-01-23

[RESTful API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaKSS.png)
When you check the picture of the API, you'll find out that the date is the key and its value is an object of all costs. So, I have to separate them all.

[Line Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nml8z.png)

```
function App() {
  const [euroCurrencyData, setEuroCurrencyData] = useState([]);
  const [dateData, setDateData] = useState([]);
  const [candianCurrencyData, setCandianCurrencyData] = useState([]);

  // CHART DATA
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({
    labels: dateData.map((date) => date),
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "EUR",
        data: euroCurrencyData.map((currency) => currency.EUR),
        backgroundColor: ["red", "green", "blue", "black"],
      },
      {
        label: "CAD",
        data: candianCurrencyData.map((currency) => currency.CAD),
        backgroundColor: ["green", "blue", "yellow", "green"],
      },
    ],
  });

  // EURO FETCH

  const getEuroData = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(
      "https://api.freecurrencyapi.com/v1/historical?apikey=fGfh2W2M2jvc4drZkLCdOUhJSvQqRn0ZONHPWvTq&currencies=EUR&date_from=2022-12-23T07%3A50%3A10.865Z&date_to=2023-01-23T07%3A50%3A10.866Z"
    );

    const data = res.data.data;
    const euroCurrency = Object.values(data);
    const currencyDate = Object.keys(data);

    setEuroCurrencyData(euroCurrency);

    setDateData(currencyDate);
  };

  // CANDIAN FETCH

  const getCandianData = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(
      "https://api.freecurrencyapi.com/v1/historical?apikey=fGfh2W2M2jvc4drZkLCdOUhJSvQqRn0ZONHPWvTq&currencies=CAD&date_from=2022-12-23T13%3A05%3A35.472Z&date_to=2023-01-23T13%3A05%3A35.473Z"
    );

    const data = res.data.data;
    const candianCurrency = Object.values(data);

    setCandianCurrencyData(candianCurrency);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getEuroData();
    getCandianData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="line-chart-container">
        <LineChart chartData={chartData} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

```
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
import { Chart as ChartJS } from "chart.js";
import Chart from "chart.js/auto";
const LineChart = ({ chartData }) => {
  return <Line data={chartData} />;
```

};

Comment: Why ChartJS imported two times?

Comment: I copied it mistakenly. Let me edit it.